# Are Saddle Tees Acceptable According To Plumbing Code

Tags: plumbing

I’ve been meaning to add a new fixture in my bathroom for a shower. The problem is the current way the drains are plumbed doesn’t allow enough slope for the horizontal parts of the new drain (tailpiece? tailpipe?) because the old drains are very old and we’re likely installed before these codes existed. Because of this, I am going to need to put a new branch is on the cast iron stack. I’ve been trying to research the best way to do this without having to cut a section of it and install a wye that’s connected to the iron pipe with no-hub connections, mainly because that is going to be quite the arduous task.

However, everything I’ve found says that is *the* way to do it. But the other day I saw this saddle tee on Amazon and ordered one, because it looks like it will save me from having to cut a section of the iron pipe. The documentation that came with the tee says that it will work on the iron pipe as long as I use an additional gasket, which I also ordered. It also came with some U clamps that hold it to the pipe, and the smaller pipe gets solvent-welded into it.

However I can’t find anything in the codes that says whether or not using one of these is acceptable. So my question is, to the plumbing experts/professionals here, is using a saddle tee a code compliant way to add a branch? (The town in which I live just uses the IPC for its codes)

[image]

Comment: I'm curious... how do you intend to cut a port in the iron pipe, and how is that less difficult than cutting out a section?

Comment: With a hole saw. If I cut a section of the stack, I would need to support it somehow, since the top portion is going to want to collapse. If I cut just a hole, the stack still supports itself.

Comment: Yes, but only temporarily. The wye will carry the load if you're not in a skyscraper.

Comment: Right, but even if it’s only temporarily it’s still going to be much more work; I don’t have to worry about large objects falling down the stack, or the upper part of the stack collapsing while cutting it, or the saw that I cut the pipe with binding up under the weight of the stack, etc.